# Is there a way to embed Jupyter notebooks in Dokuwiki?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dokuwiki

I am looking for a way to embed Jupyter notebooks in Dokuwiki and, if possible, run them from there.
As an option, the notebooks and all data for them may physically lie in a GitHub repository.